# System.out.println says out cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I write System.out.println(), eclipse complains that out cannot be resolved or is not a field.
also i am Try this import static java.lang.System.out;

In other files of the project all working fine.
I have clean Project,restart eclipse but all in vain.
I have even delete that file and create new file but still problem exists. 
I am clue less now. Please help me if any one have any idea.

Thank you.

Comment: shows us some snippet of code

Comment: Use Log.i() or others Log.* functions

Comment: @Sharpedge is not true. It will print on the log the same way Log.d does

Comment: @bobbel yes you can... with static imports

Comment: @PhilippSander: yes, i misread it! ;)

Comment: @blackbelt you mean Log.i, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eclipse automatically imported **android.provider.Settings.System** I removed this Import solved my problem

Comment: you should have deleted the question.